# Raspberry PI network topology for mobile ITO applications

Tags: wifi

I’m working on a project where we use a Raspberry Pi to read and log live sensor data from various sources. Sensor data is delivered to the PI over USB.

The next step would be interfacing with this sensor data from and iOS and Android mobile application. This needs to happen over WiFi due to high data throughout. BLE is not an option.

The caveat here is that we need the connected mobile devices to retain internet connection over cellular data while at the same time have an open connection to the Pi over websockets/mqtt or similar.

This also needs to happen without fiddling with WiFi settings on the mobile device. In other words, from the mobile side, it needs to be a “consumer grade” experience with no hacks or workarounds.

This may be asked here before, but so far I’ve only found old answers or general directions and no absolute “yes, we’ve done it and this is how” or “no, we tried and this is why it doesn’t work”

So, my questions are:

1) Is this possible?
2) If you have experience with this, how did you set up the WiFi? Adhoc? 
3) Did you have to handle network connections in any particular way on the mobile side?

Comment: Are these questions to configure a mobile device? How is the Raspberry Pi involved?

Answer (score -1):

<s>I would think If you set up a local dns, with a sub-domain pointing toward your pi's ip, that should give you what you need.</s>

UPDATE:
To have both a wifi connection to the pi and a cellular internet connection, then do the following

On the IOS device establish a wifi connection with the pi and tap the (i) symbol next to the wifi network connection and configure the IP address to manual.
Enter an IP address and subnet mask in the same range as the pi

IP Address : 10.0.1.4 (for example)
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0

Make sure you leave Router, DNS, and Search Domains blank! This tells the iPhone that it should use its cellular network to route internet traffic rather than trying to do it via WiFi.

Comment: Maybe I wasn’t clear, but the PI doesn’t have networking, hence the need for the mobile devices to retain internet access via cellular on an OS level. 

I don’t see how a local DNS solves anything.

Comment: But what has this to do with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hey again Dex. Thanks for the reply, but this isn't exactly "consumer grade" because it requires workarounds in the internet settings.